# I'm trying to upload a varchar image from my mysql database and it's not working. Any suggestions?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, image

I'm using 000webhost for my php server and phpmyadmin for my database. My image row looks like

```
image   varchar(100)    utf8_unicode_ci
```

What i'm trying to do is someone inputs a username and it outputs the image associated with that username. Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<form action="showimage.php" method="GET">
<h2>Show Image</h2>
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Show Image" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and my php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php


$host='localhost';
$user='id1783920_123456';
$pass='';
$db='id1783920_mydb';

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
if($con) {
//echo 'connected successfully to id1783920_mydb database<br><br>';
}

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM 'blob' WHERE 'id'='$id'"); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) {

$imagedata = $row[`image`];  

}

echo"$imagedata"; 
mysqli_close($con);

?>

<img src="showimage.php?username=$_GET['username']">

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please give me some suggestions? Thanks so much!
I also keep getting this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /storage/h11/920/1783920/public_html/Complete/showimage.php on line 23

Comment: Double quotes are what I'm using and that's what I'm supposed to use. So that's not the issue.

Comment: you dont use single qoutes around a table name and column name never ever..

Comment: Yes, it is the issue. Please read the dup link. You're supposed to use backticks for column names and table names, not single or double quotes.

Comment: ...what...where are my single quotes around a table or column name?

Comment: `'blob' WHERE 'id' =` should be `\`blob\` WHERE \`id\` =`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm still getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /storage/h11/920/1783920/public_html/Complete/showimage.php on line 23

Comment: your code is failing on too many levels. Best you go read the manuals on those functions. You will see the proper syntax.

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis on the line with the where statement.

Comment: lol. I've never got that before:) Can I use that quote? @Fred-ii-

Comment: oh sure; I've no copyright on it ;-)

Comment: I'm gonna close this question...Fred is right :( I just want to add a profile pic to my users home page but looks like that wont work because "My code is failing on too many levels" - Fred P.S How do you close a question?

Answer (score 0):

The error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /storage/h11/920/1783920/public_html/Complete/showimage.php on line 23

is because:

```
$imagedata = $row[`image`];
```

should be:

```
$imagedata = $row['image'];
```

Backticks are very useful in MySQL queries. But in the PHP code it is normally either single or double-quotes. For a constant text value it makes no real difference, but if you want to have variables inside the string (e.g., `$row["image{$counter}"]`) then you need to use double-quotes.